# System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception : Access is Denied when accessing process path

Tags: c#, windows, permissions

I am trying to access a process filename but I keep getting this access is denied error, I tried looking up the error online but I do not seem to understand any of the solutions, is there an easy way to overcome this error. Sorry for the lousy question, I am still very new to c#

I have tried checking access rights to the paths but to no avail since administrators are already included

```
    foreach (Process process in processList)
            {
               dataGridView1.Rows.Add(process.ProcessName, process.Id, 
               BytesToReadableValue(process.PrivateMemorySize64);

                // trying to find the path of the process
                string path = process.MainModule.FileName;
                Console.WriteLine(path);
            }
```

System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'Access is denied'

Comment: Does you progress runs under administrator rights?

Comment: how do i check that @Stefan

Comment: 1) if running from debugger: right click visual studio; select: run as administrator and try again. 2) if running the exe: right click exe; select: run as administrator

Comment: @Stefan if youre referring to the process, they're all just process that are currently running on my machine, I am not running my own created process

Comment: The process runs under a user, check if the user matches the rights for the path, see: https://mywindowshub.com/see-user-process-running-windows-10/